# How to replace text in another application with a specified text in my application

Tags: java, android, text

My question is in the title,
How to replace text in another application with a specified text in my application?

If possible please help me on how to do that thing

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to replace text in another application with a specified text in my application?

You don't, unless that other application offers some sort of API for doing this.

Comment: sorry but are you sure ?

Comment: @phplover: Anything else would be a security violation. You cannot simply hack into somebody else's app and replace stuff.

Comment: No I didn't mean the code, I meant to replace text while entering it in the text field like textexpander application in blackberry phones

Comment: @phplover: You can put stuff on the clipboard with `ClipboardManager`. You can write a replacement input method editor (a.k.a., "soft keyboard"). And the other application might offer an API that you can use. That is it. Anything else, again, would be a security violation. Only insecure operating systems allow arbitrary applications to change the contents of fields in arbitrary other applications.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  It really depends.  If you are on windows, you can change text in other applications using the win32 apis though C# code.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on windows you do what I was doing in my post(link below) and apparently you need to repaint as well sometimes...(no need for target app to have an api).

[How to set text on "another" win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888710/how-to-set-text-on-another-win32-application)

Comment: This question is tagged "android", not "windows".

Comment: lol....ah, good point....dumb mistake, didn't notice the tags. eh, well, human I guess.